# TypeError: Cannot read property 'native' of undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am implementing firebase phone number authentication in React Native app. I am following this documentation:
https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/auth/phone-auth

This successfully runs:

```
const {confirm} = await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(value);
this.setState({confirm})
console.log(confirm)     // is a function
```

Now when I run confirm(code):

```
    try {
      await this.state.confirm('123456');
      // Successful login - onAuthStateChanged is triggered
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e); // Invalid code
    }
```

It gives the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'native' of undefined.

I have searched a lot, but couldn't solve it. Please help.
[image: Error Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do like something

```
this.state = {confirmResult: null};
```

Then

```
const confirmResult = await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(value);
this.setState({confirmResult});
```

And Then

```
const { confirmResult } = this.state;

try {
   await confirmResult.confirm('123456');
   // Successful login - onAuthStateChanged is triggered
} catch (e) {
   console.error(e); // Invalid code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. You saved my time. Can you please tell me, how did you figure it out. Or what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have now assigned a function from a variable but are running it from a status value. Run on a variable.

```js
try {
  await confirm('123456'); // User entered code
  // Successful login - onAuthStateChanged is triggered
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e); // Invalid code
}
```

Comment: I am actually storing it in the state when confirm is generated. That's why I am running it from the state.